# Trying to turn rows of data into 4 columns of data...with a twist in Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to turn rows of data into 4 columns of data.

All data is currently in 1 Column and tens of thousands of
rows. Each user *usually* has 4 rows of data associated with them:

- Username1
- ID1
- Email1
- LastLogIn1
- Username2
- ID2
- Email2
- LastLogIn2
- etc...

However, if a user has never logged in, there is no 4th row
there for them, the next row just continues on to the
next. For example:

- Username3
- ID3
- Email3
- LastLogIn3
- Username4
- ID4
- Email4
- Username5
- ID5
- Email5
- LastLogIn5

(See how User 4 has no 4th line for LastLogIn)

If *all* users had exactly 4 rows associated with them, I
could pretty easily turn all the rows into 4 columns
with the function:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*4-4+COLUMN(A1))
```

But it's the sometimes missing 4th row that has me confused.
Anyone have any thoughts about how I could do something like:

1. Grab first row and turn it in to Column 1.
2. Grab 2nd row and turn it in to Column 2.
3. Grab 3rd row and turn it in to Column 3.
4. Grab 4th row if it begins with "Last" and turn
   it in to Column 4, if "Last" isn't there Column 4 = "NEVER".

Comment: Why was your [original version of this question](https://superuser.com/posts/1819499/revisions) filled with odd Microsoft HTML tags?

Comment: I couldn't figure out a good way to format my text, so made it look nice in Microsoft Word, then copied that HTML code

Comment: Please don’t do that. Excessive HTML formatting is not needed. This site uses [Markdown](https://superuser.com/editing-help) which is a far simpler way to cleanly format in text without HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another proposal for a bit older versions of Excel. I have used LET function but it can be easily eliminated at the expense of lengthening the formula.
Formula for `C2` may be copied to `D2:E2`. Formula in `F2` is different.
[image: Distribution]
Formula in `C2` and copy right to `E2`:

```
=INDEX($A:$A, 4*COUNTA(C$1:C1)-COUNTIF($F$1:$F1, "NEVER")+COLUMN(A1))&""
```

Formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(test, INDEX($A:$A, 4*COUNTA(F$1:F1)-COUNTIF($F$1:$F1, "NEVER")+COLUMN(D1)),
 IF(LEFT(test,4)="Last", test, IF(test="", "", "NEVER")))
```

Then copy `C2:F2` down as required.

Comment: Wow! This is some beautiful code. I think this works best for what I want to do. Thnx much!

Comment: Thanks for adding the code as text.
*Caveat: if any of the cells `C1:F1` contain text this will return wrong results.*

Comment: Yes, cells `C1:F1` should be empty. Or you should use different formulas in the first row of results.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft 365 you could use:

```
=LET(u,FILTER(ROW(A1:A19),LEFT(A1:A19)="U"),MAKEARRAY(ROWS(u),4,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(x,INDEX(A:A,INDEX(u,r)+c-1),IF(c<4,x,IF(LEFT(x)="U","NEVER",x))))))
```

or

```
=REDUCE({"Username","ID","Email","LastLogin"},FILTER(ROW(A1:A19),LEFT(A1:A19)="U"),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(z,TOROW(INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(4,,y))),IFNA(VSTACK(x,TOROW(IF(LEFT(z)={"U","I","E","L"},z,NA()),2)),"NEVER"))))
```

[image]